# Django rawSQL in migration : error in your SQL syntax, but SQL is correct

Tags: python, mysql, django, migration

I have a very tiny migration that looks like this for my django app (mysql backend)

```
operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Mileage',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True,
                                    serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('miles', models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=1)),
            ('start_location', models.CharField(max_length=255)),
            ('end_location', models.CharField(max_length=255)),
        ],
    ),
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Trip',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True,
                                    serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('start_location', models.CharField(max_length=255)),
            ('end_location', models.CharField(max_length=255)),
            ('trip_date', models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='trip date')),
        ],
    ),
    migrations.RunSQL('mymileages.sql'),
]
```

The `mymileages.sql` file looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO `mileage_mileage` (`miles`, `start_location`, `end_location`) VALUES
(3.7, 'Location 1', 'Location A'),
(2.4, 'Location 2', 'Location B'),
(4.3, 'Location 3', 'Location C');
```

I can run that SQL outside of the migration and it works fine and without issue.

When I run the migration however, it gives me the error:

`Programming error: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'mymileages.sql' at line 1")`

Comment: I'm not super familiar with django, but I think RunSQL is using`mymileages.sql` as the query, not the correct query within the mymileages.sql file.

Comment: bro migrations are for creating the table , how are you inserting it through the migration file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others had pointed out - I was going about this incorrectly.

I've since added a fixture and will use that file for bringing in the data.

First I had to add my data to the table (I just ran the SQL file manually to add it to the appropriate table).

Then I ran

`manage.py dumpdata mileage.mileage --indent 2 --format=json --output initial_mileages.json`

That created my fixture, which I then loaded with

`loaddata`

and it imported beautifully.